# How to chain annotation in Django ORM?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a table like this

```
a | b | c | sample_type | value
1   2   3     xx            0
1   34  45    yy            1
1   2   3     xx            1
```

Now I want to find the unique row count(unique based on the values combined by column a, b, c), `sum('values)` group by `sample_type` in Django ORM.

So far I have tried this

```
values('sample_type', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'values')\
        .annotate(positive_temp=Sum('values'), total_temp=Count('a'))\
        .values(name=F('sample_type'), pos=F('values'), tot=F('total_temp'))\
        .annotate(positive=Sum('pos'), total=Sum('tot'))
```

but on the last `annotate` it throws error `can not do sum on aggregated values`

Comment: Getting a little lost on the strategy of your query. Where did `values` come from in the first `.annotate`? You don't have it in the `.values` function that's right before it.

Comment: I have updated the query. It was a typo.

Comment: And what's the point of having the second `.values` ? Because you're only taking values from previous function and doing nothing with them.

Comment: My idea is to find unique count based on column `a, b,c` then run a aggregate(`sum`) based on `sample_type`.